# Writing a spreadsheet script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

[image: Google Spreadsheet]

The above link is a picture of the Google Docs spreadsheet that I am working on. 
Basically it is a sale ticket for a small appliance parts store.

I need to be able to select a range of rows and have them moved to another sheet.

If there is ever an "X" in column H, I need the script to copy the sale ticket and move it to another sheet. How do can I tell the script how big of a range to copy? The number of rows will vary depending on how many items are on the sale ticket. Most likely anywhere between 11-15 rows.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Javascript. Any help would be very very appreciated.

**Edit**, one idea is to have have it so when it detects an "x" in column H, it counts down the column until it finds the words "Amount Due". I just don't know how to implement this.

Comment: why do you create a database application in a spreadsheet?

Comment: It's much better than what we currently have. Do you think you could help me with the script?

Comment: no. alternative, click demo here: http://www.phppointofsale.com/ (it is free software written in php)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [Google Apps Script](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/), which is a new JavaScript-based scripting language developed for Google Apps. According to this description from Google, you can create custom spreadsheet functions.

> Google Apps Script is a JavaScript cloud scripting language that provides easy ways to automate tasks across Google products and third party services.
>
> With Google Apps Script you can:
>
> - Automate repetitive business processes (e.g. expense approvals,
>     time-sheet tracking, ticket management, order fulfillment, and much
>     more)
> - Create custom spreadsheet functions

While I can't provide you with the syntax needed to solve your problem, I am pretty sure GOogle Apps Script can work for you.